# A complex integral question

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem is in the Cauchy Integral Formula section in Gamelin's "Complex Analysis".
$$
\oint_{|z-1|=3} \frac{dz}{z(z^2-4)e^z}
$$
I have trouble with it because -2 is actually on the boundary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be treated as [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), i.e

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \operatorname{P.V.} \oint_{|z-1|=3} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z (z^2-4) \mathrm{e}^z} &=& 
   \frac{1}{2} \left( \oint_{|z-1|=3^+} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z (z^2-4) \mathrm{e}^z} + \oint_{|z-1|=3^-} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z (z^2-4) \mathrm{e}^z} \right) \\
   &=& 2 \pi i \left( \left. \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-z}}{z^2-4} \right|_{z=0} + 
     \left.  \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-z}}{z(z+2)} \right|_{z=2} +
     \frac{1}{2} \left.  \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-z}}{z(z-2)} \right|_{z=-2}
   \right) \\
   &=& 2 \pi i \left( -\frac{1}{4} + \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-2}}{8} + \frac{\mathrm{e}^{2}}{16} \right)
 \end{eqnarray}
$$

---

**Added**: Also can be done using *Mathematica*:

```
In[217]:= TrigToExp[
 Integrate @@ {1/(z (z^2 - 4) Exp[z]) Dt[z]/Dt[phi] /. 
    z -> 1 + (3) Exp[I phi], {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, PrincipalValue -> True}]

Out[217]= -I Pi/2 + I Pi/(4 E^2) + 1/8 I E^2 Pi
```

Comment: (Principal value, to be precise.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you, I have just corrected the spelling.

Comment: I dont understand the solution, whats going on here, please teach me